# React - Como criar um evento para um botão que ao clicar leva o cursor para um input de pesquisa na página

Tags: javascript, react, react-dom

Fala, galera! Meu primeiro post aqui no site. Queria saber como conseguiria criar um evento de clique pra esse componente Header "Digite algum termo de pesquisa ..." o qual ao clicar leva o meu cursor do teclado pra selecionar o input logo abaixo de pesquisa. Estou aprendendo ainda e não sei muito sobre a linguagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Crie uma ref para seu input com useRef do react:

```
const inputRef = useRef(null)
```

Passe a ref para o input:

```
<input ref={inputRef} />
```

Adicione o evento "onClick" no seu header, fazendo chamar a seguinte função:

```
function handleFocus() {
    inputRef.current.focus()
}
```

Informações sobre o useRef: https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).